# Foreach Loop Iteration count incorrect

Tags: c#, list, foreach, iteration

I have an IList with 38 records, when I iterate through it using foreachloop, it only iterates twice. I can't figure out why that is!

```
foreach (UserRecord rec in userlist)
{
    dictionary.Add(rec.Login, rec.Group);
}
```

Any thoughts would be a huge help.

Comment: Did you debug it? Put a breakpoint and, in Immediate Window type `userlist.Count`

Comment: Are all the entries in your userList item all UserRecord items? Have you confirmed that userList contains 38 items when it enters the userList? Where is your definition of userList?

Comment: How do you know userlist has 38 records?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I have a breakpoint inside the loop, and it only hits twice. When I view the List size in debugging mode, it shows 38 records. But still the foreach loops only twice.

Comment: Well maybe it's a dodgy `IList` implementation. We don't have *nearly* enough information to work it out at the moment. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe Add method breaking the loop?

Comment: Do you have an *exception* thrown when trying to add into dictionary?

Comment: we can't tell anything about your problem in its actual state

Comment: Ok so I converted the IList to List using :
{ userlist.ToList()). Now the problem is more evident. The list is populated with only two records.

Comment: The viewer in debugging mode was actually previewing an incorrect number of rows for IList. That became evident when I converted the type to List. Note that IList doesn't support .Count property, but uses a method instead to dynamically calculate the number of records. My guess is that intellisense got it mixed up and hence my incorrect post.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause, IMHO, is an *exception* thrown. Let's modify your solution (for test purpose only) and *debug*:

```
foreach (UserRecord rec in userlist) {
  if (null == rec) 
    MessageBox.Show("rec is null!");              // <- put a break point here
  else if (null == rec.Login)
    MessageBox.Show("rec.Login is null!");        // <- here
  else if (dictionary.ContainsKey(rec.Login))
    MessageBox.Show("rec.Login already exists!"); // <- and here 
  else
    dictionary.Add(rec.Login, rec.Group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be an exception is being thrown when you're adding to the dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
int Count = 0;

foreach (UserRecord rec in userlist)
{
    try
    { 
        dictionary.Add(rec.Login, rec.Group); 

    } 
    catch//(Exception ex)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message + "\nStackTrace: " + ex.Stacktrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        Count++;

    }

}

MessageBox.Show("Number of iterations = " + Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < userlist.Count ; i++)
{
   try
   {
       dictionary.Add(userlist[i].Login, userlist[i].Group);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //check here witch userlist is throwing exception
   }
}
```

- for better understanding of your problems always write try catch in your code.